# Jscript element.style dont working in script.js (visual studio code)

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio

(On start sorry for my english)
I have one big problem in the last my project i dont have any problems, the problem appeared in the new project.

I have 3 files (index.html, script.js and style.css)

This is my index

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="wrap"></div>
    <div class="logo">
        <p>Dzik_Company</p>
    </div>
    <p class="load">Loading</p>
    <div class="square"></div>
</header>

<script src="script.js">
</script>
```

And this is my script.js

```
const kwadrat = document.querySelector('.square');
const loading = document.querySelector(".load");
// setTimeout(hiddenElement, 3000);
function hiddenElement() {
kwadrat.style
}
```

And here (kwadrat.style) is problem, vscode not spoiler me (.style), in the last project vscode spoiler me .style.(value).
[Ss from project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbEHH.png)
[SS in last project (spoiler)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvgHq.png)
Can you help me?

Comment: i don't understand what problem do you have... after style you must declare css property like this kwadrat.style.background = "red"

Comment: This isn't really a coding question. Patryk is asking why `style` doesn't appear in VSCode's drop downdown list when he enters the first few letters. Apparently it did in the last project.

Comment: Yes Andy i enter first few letter and i dont see spoiler. (yes my english is very bad)

Comment: Weirdly I think this is to do with `document.querySelector` and classes. For example, I can do `document.querySelector('button')` and it will work, but `document.querySelector('.button')` will not. Give it a go. This is an issue with vscode. I suggest logging a bug report with the support team, or see if this an issue anyone else has reported before, but this isn't a question SO can reliably answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a coding question - it's a question about IDE behaviour.

Comment: Wow is working, thanks Andy and sorry for trouble. A report this

Comment: This is not a bug and is a coding question. Please see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `style` property only exists on html elements. However a query selector like `'.square'` may return any type of element. VS Code cannot know that it will return a `div` or even that it will return an html element.

You can use a jsdoc type annotation to let VS Code know what this querySelector returns an HTMLElement:

```
/** @type {HTMLElement} */
const kwadrat = document.querySelector('.square');
```

[image]